# Get picklist value in table header by using Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have hotel object where custom pick-list field days I need to get days field values(Sunday to Saturday) in table header by using vf page dynamically.
I wrote an apex class where i get all value but i am unable to implement in vf page how to do it?

Apex class:

```
public with sharing class dayextension {
    public List<string> stages {get;set;}
    public List<string> types {get;set;}
    Public Hotel__c hotel {get;set;}
    public boolean displayPopup {get; set;}    
    public dayextension (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        stages = new list<string>();
        types = new list<string>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Hotel__c.Days__c.getDescribe();
        System.debug(fieldResult);
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues(); 
        system.debug('--ple -->>'+ple);              
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){
           stages.add(f.getLabel());
        }
        hotel = [select id,Days__c from Hotel__c where id=: controller.getRecord().id];
        system.debug('--hotel-->>'+hotel);
    }
}
```

Vf Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Hotel__c" extensions="dayextension">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!stages}" var="dbItem">
            <apex:repeat value="{!stages}">
                <apex:column value="{!hotel.Days__c}"/> 

            </apex:repeat>    
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do but try this with your [repeat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm) block:

```
        <apex:repeat value="{!stages}" var="stage">
            <apex:column value="{!stage}"/> 
        </apex:repeat>
```

That should print a column for each picklist value.